# Random erasing from std::list?

Tags: c++, list

I'm changing a vector to a list and I'm having a few issues.

This code is now incorrect:

```
    privateChildren.erase(privateChildren.begin() +
            getPrivateChildIndex(widget));
```

How should this be resolved. The user gives the index of the widget they want to erase.

Thanks

getPrivateChildIndex returns the index of the private child. So if I pushed 3 children, getPrivateChildIndex(thirdElem) would return 2.

Comment: you have to explain more :   what is getPrivateChildIndex(). what is the return type and value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have to access the container by index, then using `std::list` might be a bad idea to begin with. In reality, there are very few situations, in which it is an appropriate container choice.

Second, how does `getPrivateChildIndex` discover the index? If it iterates through the list, then it can return an iterator, instead of an index. Then you would be able to simply do:

```
privateChildren.erase(getPrivateChild(widget));
```

Finally, if you are sure that you want to use a linked list and you have to use an index, then what you need is the `std::advance` function:

```
#include <iterator>
int index(getPrivateChildIndex(widget));
privateChildren.erase(std::advance(privateChildren.begin(), index));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, for either the vector or the list version, you'd not obtain an index but an iterator from `getPrivateChildIndex(widget)` (e.g. using `std::find()` or `std::find_if()`). If you absolutely need to return in index, you can use `std::advance()` to move to the position you probably just found in `getPrivateChildIndex()`.